# Scala MouseEvent - How to know which button was pressed?

Tags: swing, scala, scala-2.8

I'm writing a scala application using scala swing. I can listen for `MouseClicked` to get notified whenever the mouse is clicked, but how do i know which button was pressed. The documentation is pretty bad, so i have looked in the Java documentation for `MouseEvent`, which says that the key can be retrieved from the modifiers field, so i tried to output the modifiers field of the scala `MouseClicked` event, which turned out to be an integer, 0 for left click, mouse button 3 and mouse button 4 and 256 for right click.

It looks like it will work if i only need to know the difference between left and right click, but can i be sure the modifiers all ways work this way? The documentation says nothing, and for what i know modifiers could be affected by other things than just which mouse button was pressed. I would also like to know the difference between left click and mouse button 3 and 4. I don't think users expect them to do the same thing as left click.

In the scala documentation there is a `MouseButtonEvent`, can this be used for anything? The documentation says nothing about what it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use `x.peer.getButton` to get the Java mapping (where `x` is your Scala `MouseClicked` event).  `peer` almost always contains a Java equivalent to the Scala class--and it does in this case.

Comment: Eclipse with the scala plugin won't compile, when i have this in my code: e.peer.BUTTON1 from what i've read, i should be able to access static fields in my scala code. Am i doing something wrong, or should i get another IDE?

Comment: You have to access them via the class, not via the instance: `if (e.peer.getButton == java.awt.event.MouseEvent.BUTTON1)`, as an example.

Comment: Thank you... i had completely forgotten that.