# Right Click on a Button / Scala

Tags: swing, scala, button, right-click

I'm currently trying to code a minesweeper using scala, but I can't find the way to listen to a right click on a button.

I've already searched on the Internet the way to do it, but I definitely was not able to find it.

If anyone could help me out, I would be really grateful :)

Thanks,

Schnipp

(Note: Scala is a new language to me and I am not a Java user, so I am sorry if my questions sound dumb)

EDIT:

I am trying to find (or implement) a function 'ButtonClickedRight' that could listen to a right-click on a button.

like this

```
import scala.swing._
import scala._
import scala.swing.event._

object Right extends MainFrame with App {
    title = ""
    visible = true

    val b = new button("")
    listenTo(b)
    reactions += {
       case ButtonClicked(`b`) => *code*
       case ButtonClickedRight(`b`) => *code*
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 --

I would like to know if the user has clicked on the Button "1" or not. The problem I have is that this code prints "Mouse clicked at " + e.point+" type "+e.modifiers when I click on the label but not on the button.

```
object App extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  lazy val ui = new GridPanel(2,1) {
    contents += new Button("1")
    contents += new Label("2")
    listenTo(mouse.clicks)
    reactions += {
      case e: MouseClicked =>
        println("Mouse clicked at " + e.point+" type "+e.modifiers)
    }
  }
  def top = new MainFrame {
    contents = ui
    visible = true
    preferredSize = new Dimension(500,500)
  }
}
```

Comment: Which graphics toolkit/library are you using? Assuming Swing, your google-fu is weak: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877117/how-do-i-recognize-mouse-clicks-in-scala and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700730/scala-mouseevent-how-to-know-which-button-was-pressed

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I had seen these two questions before posting but I can't understand how it works.  I am sorry my question was not clear enough (I am indeed using swing). I've edited the question.

Comment: So, what's working or not working? What error are you getting? What is happening and what did you expect?

Comment: I would like to know if the user has right-clicked on a button. I don't know how to add some code in a comment, so I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Button events are fired through a specific publisher `.mouse.clicks`.

```
import scala.swing._
import scala.swing.event._

object App extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  lazy val ui = new GridPanel(2,1) {
    val button = new Button("1")
    contents += button
    contents += new Label("2")
    listenTo(button.mouse.clicks) // !
    reactions += {
      case evt @ MouseClicked(`button`, pt, _, _, _) =>
        val which = evt.peer.getButton
        if (which > 1) {
          println(s"Mouse clicked at (${pt.x}; ${pt.y}) - button: $which")
        }
    }
  }
  lazy val top = new MainFrame {
    contents = ui
    size = new Dimension(500,500)
  }
}
```

Note that at least on Linux my right button has number 3 not 2. You could also use the `triggersPopup` flag, but then you must ensure to monitor both `MousePressed` and `MouseReleased`, as this flag is platform-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are on the right path, for my understanding of scala swings I think that the problem is that you are not attaching the listener correctly. For one I would assign the button to a value and call listenTo only on it:

```
val button = new Button("1")
listenTo(button)
```

Then, in the reactions, I would write the pattern checking in the event that it comes from the button (probably redundant if you only call `listenTo` passing the button) and that it has the correct button:

```
case ButtonClicked(b) if b == button && b.peer.getButton == MouseEvent.BUTTON_2 => ...
```

So the code you provided in your edit would become:

```
object App extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  lazy val ui = new GridPanel(2,1) {
    val button = new Button("1")
    contents += button
    contents += new Label("2")
    listenTo(button)
    reactions += {
      case evt @ MouseClicked(b, pt, _, _, _) if b == button && evt.peer.getButton == java.awt.event.MouseEvent.BUTTON2 =>
        println(s"Mouse clicked at (${pt.x}; ${pt.y}) - button: ${evt.peer.getButton}")
    }
  }
  def top = new MainFrame {
    contents = ui
    visible = true
    preferredSize = new Dimension(500,500)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd love to award this bounty, but I'd need the code to actually compile in Scala (preferably 2.11).  I'm getting the following errors:

 `object MouseEvent is not a member of package scala.swing.event Note: class MouseEvent exists, but it has no companion object.
value getButton is not a member of javax.swing.AbstractButton`

Comment: The reason is that the `MouseEvent` I am referring to is from `java.awt`. I updated my code example, please let me know if neither that compiles.

Comment: thanks -- still getting `value getButton is not a member of javax.swing.AbstractButton`

Comment: apparently `ButtonClicked` extends `ActionEvent`, whereas `MouseEvent` extends `InputEvent`.  Thoughts?

Comment: Right, I made another mistake, I edited it, I wonder if there is any way to use the `Modifiers` from the event rather than resorting to the awt peer but I couldn't find any.

Comment: this isn't printing anything for me, even after removing the `if` tests precedent to the `println` statement in the pattern matching.

Comment: or to keep it classy you could just not respond.  that'd be high status.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
new Button {
   listenTo(mouse.clicks)
   reactions += {
     case MouseClicked(_, _, c, _, _) => handleClick(c == 0)
   }
}

def handleClick(isLeftClick: Boolean): Unit = {
   //
}
```